Select x-axis range by brush in a plot inside a box
In Shiny, I select an x-axis range by brushing a plot, as in the MWE below:
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
library(shinydashboard)


test_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)

  brush_options <- brushOpts(id = ns("brush"), fill = "#99CCFF", stroke = "#003366", opacity = 0.25,
                             delay = 1, delayType = "debounce", clip = TRUE,
                             direction = "x", resetOnNew = TRUE)

  tagList(
    plotOutput(outputId = ns("plot"), brush = brush_options, height=600, width=1600)
  )
}


test_server <- function(id){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = drat)) + geom_point()
    })

  })
}

demoApp <- function() {
  ui <- fluidPage(
    test_ui("demo")
  )
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    test_server("demo")
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)  
}

demoApp()

which produces:

However, now I have a very wide plot that I place inside a box to allow for x-axis scrolling to visualize it. Like this:
  tagList(
    box(style='width:600px;overflow-x:scroll;',
        plotOutput(outputId = ns("plot"), brush = brush_options, height=600, width=1600)
    )
  )

But when trying the brush selection on that, this happens:

Is it possible to have these 2 things work in agreement (brush selection of a scrollable plot)? The ideal would be to have the scroll bar move as you do the brush selection.
